# File Uploud Selenium Python with dialog box

Tags: python, selenium

```
cereretip_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body/apmc-root[1]/div[1]/apmc-permisauto-add[1]/form[1]/div[17]/div[1]/a[1]/fa-icon[1]/*[1]')
cereretip_field.send_keys('C:\\Users\\sorin\\Desktop\\Python\\cerere.pdf')
```

The web application i test, have an button to uploud -> then you take what do you want for uploud from a dialog box -> enter
Why this is isnt work ?

Comment: which website are you trying to scrape the data from

Comment: From something private, they button for uploud is an svg

Comment: "//body/apmc-root[1]/div[1]/apmc-permisauto-add[1]/form[1]/div[17]/div[1]/a[1]/fa-icon[1]/*[1]" Such locator is garbage. Never use it.

Comment: Add part of html you are looking at to your question, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.